# My Material Viewport shading goes black

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

So this has been going for a while now and its becoming a real problem for me. Heres whats happening.

Material Preview:

[image: Material Preview]

Rendered Preview:

[image: Rendered Preview]

Solid Preview:

[image: Solid Preview]

Comment: hello, how does your Viewport Shading panel look like?

Comment: [ShaderPanel](https://i.gyazo.com/83e2f9796fccf4281273170f002985c8.png)